# Problem in execution of callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

```
checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL, success, error){
     $.ajax({
            url: "",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(json){
                success.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            error:function(){
                error.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        })
}

function validateSearchStirng(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage){
         checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL, function(){
                getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);  
             }, function(){
                var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" ><b>Solr Server Not Runing </b></font><hr /> ";
                removeList();
                $("#result").html(msg); 
         });
}
```

What i want to do is to call  `getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL)` in case of success and in case of failure i want a msg.
but the behaivour of the above function is as :
it is calling `getSolrResponse()` before it is calling to `checkSolrServerAvailibility()` 
would you please tell me the behavior of the above two function in which order they are executing.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT , ok, maybe we could do it in another way (just call the function you want on success or error):

```
function validateSearchStirng(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage){
         checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL );
}

checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL){
     $.ajax({
            url: "",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(){
            getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);  
         },
            error: function(){
            var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" ><b>Solr Server Not Runing </b></font><hr /> ";
            removeList();
            $("#result").html(msg); 
     }
}
```

if you have problem in your error function at first ry this:

```
error: function(){
    alert('error');
}
```

if it works your actual function has a problem, try to install firebug for firefox and check if you have error in the console.

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: still it is doing the same. what i want is to call  getSolrResponse() in case of success. but it is called before it check for the success :(

Comment: why don't you simply call the functions on error or success inseat of passing them?I edited my answer to do so

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: when my url is not correct(server is shut down or ip is not correct ) than it is come it to the error part but it not doing so :(

Comment: if your server doesn't respond the function defined after 'error' is executed: try to put an alert as a first thing to see if it's executed. In that case you are probably doing something wrong in the function (look at my edited answer)

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: I have put alert(), and after looking at the behaviour i ma saying that if ip is not correct or server is down than also it is not executing error :(, i mean alert() never executed

Comment: my url is as http:localhost:8983/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start="+start+"&rows="+end+"&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?

Comment: but the success function is called correctly? the "error" function is called only if the server is unreachable or if there is an error in the response

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: yes exactly when server is running properly success is called but when there is a prob with server than error is not called(and success also not called)

Comment: The only thing i found out is that error is not called if the call is cross domain / jsonp but this is not your case, what does the firebug console tells to you about the failed call?What is the status code?But i really don't know how to solve this. Maybe you should ask a different question on the topic and close this as this is a different problem.